# How do I remove objects in an ordered to-many CoreData relationship in some generic way?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I've got a Contact entity with a one-to-many relationship to another entities email addresses, telephones.

This relationship (called "emails,telephones" naturally), is also ordered, so that I can display a contact's list of email addresses in a table view, and allow the user to delete or modify each one. As far as I can tell, they need to be ordered so that I can tell which one is being removed/modified: for example, if the user taps the delete button in row 1, the second email address should be removed from the relationship. Without being ordered, I wouldn't know which one to remove.

When generating the NSManagedObject subclass, I get an NSOrderedSet property on the class, and CoreData helpfully provided some accessors in the .h file:

```
@interface Contact (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)
- (void)insertObject:(PLEmail *)value inEmailsAtIndex:(NSUInteger)idx;
- (void)removeObjectFromEmailsAtIndex:(NSUInteger)idx;
- (void)insertEmails:(NSArray<PLEmail *> *)value atIndexes:(NSIndexSet *)indexes;
- (void)removeEmailsAtIndexes:(NSIndexSet *)indexes;
- (void)replaceObjectInEmailsAtIndex:(NSUInteger)idx withObject:(PLEmail *)value;
- (void)replaceEmailsAtIndexes:(NSIndexSet *)indexes withEmails:(NSArray<PLEmail *> *)values;
- (void)addEmailsObject:(PLEmail *)value;
- (void)removeEmailsObject:(PLEmail *)value;
- (void)addEmails:(NSOrderedSet<PLEmail *> *)values;
- (void)removeEmails:(NSOrderedSet<PLEmail *> *)values;

- (void)insertObject:(PLTelephone *)value inTelephonesAtIndex:(NSUInteger)idx;
- (void)removeObjectFromTelephonesAtIndex:(NSUInteger)idx;
- (void)insertTelephones:(NSArray<PLTelephone *> *)value atIndexes:(NSIndexSet *)indexes;
- (void)removeTelephonesAtIndexes:(NSIndexSet *)indexes;
- (void)replaceObjectInTelephonesAtIndex:(NSUInteger)idx withObject:(PLTelephone *)value;
- (void)replaceTelephonesAtIndexes:(NSIndexSet *)indexes withTelephones:(NSArray<PLTelephone *> *)values;
- (void)addTelephonesObject:(PLTelephone *)value;
- (void)removeTelephonesObject:(PLTelephone *)value;
- (void)addTelephones:(NSOrderedSet<PLTelephone *> *)values;
- (void)removeTelephones:(NSOrderedSet<PLTelephone *> *)values;
@end
```

My problem is that is there any way to make this code generic, so that `isKindOfClass` check should be removed:

```
NSArray *nestedArray = [orderedSet array];
    id nestedObject = [nestedArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if ([nestedObject isKindOfClass:[PLEmail class]]) {
        PLEmail *email = (PLEmail *)nestedObject;
        [email MR_deleteEntity];
        [self.contact removeEmailsObject:email];
    }
    else if ([nestedObject isKindOfClass:[PLTelephone class]]) {
        PLTelephone *telePhone = (PLTelephone *)nestedObject;
        [email MR_deleteEntity];
        [self.contact removeTelephonesObject:telePhone];
    }
```

Comment: You don't need the model to be ordered.  Instead, only your datasource has to be ordered.  But that's another story.

Comment: If MR_deleteEntity deletes the object and the delete rule is nullify, the object is automatically removed from the contact.

Comment: Delete rule is nullify, but it just makes object nil, but not removing..

Comment: Can objects be nil in ordered sets?

Comment: @Willeke no objects can't be nil in ordered sets.

Comment: Which object is made nil? Doesn't `[email MR_deleteEntity];` remove email from the emails of contact?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a reciprocal relationship (as is recommended), you can nil the Contact relationship on the email or telephone entity.  That will also remove the entity from the Contact's list.

**Sample code for dealing with multiple relationships**

```
- (void)removeRelationship:(NSString *)relationshipKeyPath fromEntity:(NSManagedObject *)entity {
    [entity setValue:nil forKeyPath:relationshipKeyPath];
}
```

You would use it like so:

```
[self removeRelationship:@"contact" fromEntity:unknownRelationshipForContact];
```

Comment: Reciprocal relationship of "Email or Telephone" entity is with many other entities as well like with "building or property and many more"  entities. In that case how can i find from which entity from contact, building, property etc i have to make email nil?

Comment: I don't think you can get away without knowing any context at all.  You have to know which kind of relationship you're severing on one side or the other.  The original question did not state that there are multiple relationships involved from both sides.

Comment: You can, however, have a generic `removeContact:` method, which doesn't care if the receiver is an `email` or a `telephone` entity.  And then do the same with `removeBuilding:`, etc.

Comment: Again same, then there will be a check for building or contact, its not generic then by the way..

Comment: You are asking for the code to read your mind.  It doesn't work that way.

Comment: Actually, you can make it slightly more generic by passing in the keyPath for the relationship you want to sever.  You can then use the primitive methods of `NSManagedObject` to deal with it.  However, that makes for fragile code and still requires *some* context, somewhere.

Comment: Could you elaborate some more on primitive methods of NSManagedObject in your suggested answer by editing it. So that i can find some more better way, as i am already passing keyPath. Thanks

Comment: OK, but please be aware that I don't consider it a better way.  Any time you are losing type-safety and syntax checking, you better have a good reason.